Removing {{ choice.tag }} in Django Template Breaks JavaScript Update Function for Radio Button Selection
In my Django application, I have a form with radio buttons for selecting the number of meals per week. The form also includes checkboxes for meal preferences. I have initialized a preselected value for these fields in my form. I use JavaScript to dynamically update a summary section based on preselected selections when page loads.
The radio buttons for meals_per_week are generated by Django and included in the HTML template. If I remove {{ choice.tag }}, the updateSummary function no longer receives the selected value for meals_per_week. How can I fix this issue while still removing {{ choice.tag }}?
Here is the relevant part of my HTML template:
{% for choice in form.meals_per_week %}
<div class="flex-fill mx-1">
    <div class="card mb-4 custom-card" data-input-id="{{ choice.id_for_label }}">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <input type="radio" class="hidden-input" id="{{ choice.id_for_label }}" name="{{ choice.name }}" value="{{ choice.choice_value }}" {% if choice.is_checked %}checked{% endif %}>
            {{ choice.tag }}
            <label class="form-check-label d-block" for="{{ choice.id_for_label }}">
                {{ choice.choice_label }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}    

And here is my JavaScript function that updates the summary:
async function updateSummary() {
const mealsPerWeek = **parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="meals_per_week"]:checked').value);**
const mealPreferences = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="meal_preference_type"]:checked')).map(el => el.value);

let response = await fetch(`/get_price?meals_per_week=${mealsPerWeek}`);
let data = await response.json();

const pricePerServing = data.price_per_serving.toFixed(2);
const planPrice = (pricePerServing * mealsPerWeek).toFixed(2);

document.getElementById('meal_preference_type').innerText = mealPreferences.join(', ');
document.getElementById('meals_per_week').innerText = mealsPerWeek;
document.getElementById('price_per_serving').innerText = pricePerServing;
document.getElementById('plan_price').innerText = planPrice;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {updateSummary();
});    

I tried to achieve the same with a simple form without any preselected fields and it worked fine. The reason I want to remove the {{ choice.tag }} is because I do not want to show the radio buttons instead select the cards/values by highlighting the color of my select.
Any help would be appreciated!

The easiest way would be just to hide what ever {{ choice.tag }} renders to the page. For a more advanced answer we need to see what actually is rendered to the source code.

your input type should be hidden (or checkbox), not radio

if you don't want to use this radio buttons then you have to assign value directly in JavaScript - maybe something like const mealsPerWeek = {{ choice.choice_value }} but it may need to get value from form.meals_per_week, or send only this value in new variable which you will use in {{...}}

frankly, I don't understand what means "select the cards/values by highlighting the color of my select.". If you plant to use something different to select value (instead of checkboxes) then you have to use different code in const mealsPerWeek = ... - but code depends on what you will use in HTML. So first create elements which you will use to "select the cards/values by highlighting the color of my select." and later change code in const mealsPerWeek = ... and later remove {{ choice.tag }}
